# How To Create An Account For pages.github.io?

Tags: email, github, github-pages

I have a website at pages.github.io. Let my username be `myname`, my website name be `myblog.github.io`. Then can I create a mail address named `myname@myblog.github.io` or `noreply@myblog.github.io`? If yes, then how do I create one? I no, then what should next I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then can I create a mail address named myname@myblog.github.io or noreply@myblog.github.io?

No. Github do not offer email hosting.

> I no, then what should next I do?

Find an email hosting service.

If you want the email to use the same hostname as the website: Buy a domain and use it for both services.